# Make-up air in basement

Tags: hvac, exhaust-fan, air, intake-fan

I got my rec room and bathroom final inspection for my basement and the inspector said I need make-up air (and a couple other things). The previous inspector for rough-in apparently didn't do his job properly.

- The rec room has a 50k btu wall heater that gravity vents out the chimney
- The bathroom fan down there is 80cfm (with 4in pipe and 1/4" hardware cloth)
- Unfinished side has an hvac system has its own intake and exhaust
- Unfinished side has a water heater that gravity vents out the chimney
- Upstairs kitchen has gas stove/oven with exhaust fan hood
- Upstairs bathrooms both have exhaust fans

I've been told I can use the [Optional Uniform Dwelling Code (UDC) Makeup and Combustion Air Worksheet](https://dsps.wi.gov/Documents/Programs/UDC/WorksheetOptionalMakeupCombustionAir.pdf) to determine how much make-up air I need but I'm unsure that I'm understanding what make-up air is, exactly.

I understand that it's there so that gravity exhausted appliances don't have a backdraft into the house but I'm unsure of how to pull in the make-up air without pulling in freezing cold air from the outdoors into the house. Can anyone help me fill out this worksheet and determine what I need?

So far my research has led me to a simple [Broan damper](https://www.broan-nutone.com/en-us/accessory/md6t) and then tying it into some sort of occupancy sensor.

Comment: Most newer homes are sealed almost air tight.  Makeup air is to replace the air used by fuel burning devices.  Some use whole house air exchangers that transfer heat from stale outgoing air to fresh incoming air.  Most fuel burning devices have the proper size small pipes that let air in close to its use(the burner).  A simple system as a pipe going outside with the end bent/turned down so only sucks cold air in as needed, instead of a pipe straight or turned up letting air in all the time.  Cold air sinks.